# Print object values inside <FlatList>

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have data as object as follow:

```
const allrptbyname =    {
                          "test1" : [
                                     {"id":11,"name":"test1","day":"MON","level":2}, 
                                     {"id":14,"name":"test1","day":"WED","level":4}
                                    ],
                           "test2" :[
                                     {"id":13,"name":"test2","day":"TUE","level":3}, 
                                     {"id":15,"name":"test2","day":"FRI","level":5}
                                     ]
                         }
```

I want to print these data inside `<FlatList>`, my FlatList looks like the following:

```
<FlatList data={allrptbyname}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <ListItem onPress={console.log("report clicked")/*() => onItemClickHandler(item)*/}>
      <Avatar.Icon color="#ffffff" backgroundColor='#ff9193' size={53} icon="file-excel" />
      <ListItem.Content>
        <ListItem.Title >
               {/* here the title will be test1, test2 and so one */}
        </ListItem.Title>
      </ListItem.Content>
     <ListItem.Chevron />
    </ListItem>
    )}
      keyExtractor={item => /* here the key will be these names test1,test1*/}
 />
```

**here an example of how the app view will look like**
[image: here an example of how the app view will look like]

Answer (score 0):

For FlatList, the data should be an array always.

Please refer [FlatList data](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#data) documentation.

In your example, *allrptbyname* is an object. So first convert it into an array and then assign it to your FlatList.

And once that is done, then something like this should work,

```
<ListItem.Title>
     {item.name}
</ListItem.Title>
```